# Edit text focus is not persistence in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a list item in `RecyclerView` that has couple of fields as `EditText`. Everytime user type something some validation is done at ViewModel and then `notifyDataSetChange()` called. Couple of issues I'm facing

- While typing some times focus get lost keyboard is there but none of the field is selected. It gets worse if I have more then 1 item
- Also I'm using `setSelection` to move the cursor to end. It makes the edit text very slow.

My ViewHolder looks like this

```
      class ViewHolder(view: View, listener: ItemListener<AuthPItem>?) :WaafiViewHolder<AuthPItem>(view, listener) {
    
        private val delete = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.del)
        private val firstName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.firstName)
        private val lastName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.lastName)

        private var firsNameTextWatcher: Watcher? = null
        private var lastNameTextWatcher: Watcher? = null

        override fun onBind(item: AuthPItem) {
            item.postion = layoutPosition

            firstName.removeTextChangedListener(firsNameTextWatcher)
            lastName.removeTextChangedListener(lastNameTextWatcher)

            firsNameTextWatcher = Watcher {
                listener?.onItemClicked(firstName, this, item)
            }
            
            lastNameTextWatcher = Watcher {
                listener?.onItemClicked(lastName, this, item)
            }

            setValues(firstName, item.person.firstName)
            setValues(lastName, item.person.lastName)

            setError(firstName, item.firstNameError)
            setError(lastName, item.lastNameError)

            firstName.addTextChangedListener(firsNameTextWatcher)
            lastName.addTextChangedListener(lastNameTextWatcher)

        }

        private fun setValues(editText: EditText?, value: String?) {
            editText?.setText(value)
            value?.length?.let { editText?.setSelection(it) }
        }

        private fun setError(editText: EditText?, firstNameError: Int?) {
            editText?.error = firstNameError?.let { context.getString(it) }
        }

        override fun onUnbind() {
        }
    }
```

I tried to do it with `OnFocuseChangeListener`. Adding and removing the listener as the focus changes and keeping the last focus item at `ViewHolder` level and `requestFocus()` `onBind()` callback.